# Readonly keyword in class declaration

Tags: c#, .net

Recently I got a little bit confused by readonly declaration of struct with comparison with classes.

Consider the following:

```
public class TheClass
{
    public readonly int X;
    public readonly int Y;
    public readonly object A;

    public TheClass(int x, int y, object a) => (X, Y, A) = (x, y, a);
}

public readonly struct TheStruct
{
    public readonly int X;
    public readonly int Y;
    public readonly object A;
    public TheStruct(int x, int y, object a) => (X, Y, A) = (x, y, a);
}
```

My question is - why there is no possibility to declare `TheClass` as `public readonly class TheClass`? That would force other fields to be declared readonly and it's easier to read as well as understand the intent of the author.

Comment: readonly structs are intended to work with `in`, see [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-in-modifier-and-the-readonly-structs-in-c/).

Comment: @canton7 not just `in` - it also allows you to call methods on `readonly` *fields* (etc - `ref readonly` too, I guess) of `struct` types; without `readonly struct`, it needs to make a defensive copy to avoid the risk of the method mutating the state of a conceptually `readonly` field; with `readonly struct`, it can just call the method on the existing field by-ref

Comment: @canton7 [illustration](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEBmAAkICZSBhUgbwFgAoU102AQwBMIA7XAJ6kAYhAikAZmNIBeUlxgSOAV1wYA3MzbsY3PoNIAhDlFLATs+YpVrNLNiXIoaHXLlEQAFAEpZAPkkxADoAEQgASQwfO21HQmdqV1xjKB9/MxNQiKjvOwBfZmYAZwwoZTAMEWk6cjJ40jDItLo80gKmTh5+IRKyiqMLGrjnRpz6VrygA==) - look at the IL of `CallFoo` vs `CallBar`

Comment: @MarcGravell It also helps reduce defensive copies in string concatenation, but it's true to say that it was introduced at the same time as `in` in C# 7.2, as `in` is useless without `readonly` methods

Comment: Note that Records are on the way, which will provide a much cleaner way to declare immutable value objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I agree that the `readonly` modifier would be *convenient* for when you're trying to explicitly make a `class` immutable, and it is a little striking that it wasn't implemented at the same time that `readonly struct` was implemented, but ultimately `readonly struct` is intended as a *necessary* feature to support the `in` usage, and when calling methods on `readonly` fields of value-types - allowing the compiler and/or runtime to avoid having to make defensive copies of things in case the method mutates them, and instead being able to pass a reference to an existing value-type. That isn't really a concept that applies with references, as it *never* makes the defensive copy.

But: totally with you on the expressive and intent parts. I'd love for `readonly class` to exist too.

---

Perhaps one reason it wasn't considered for `class` is that you'd also need the *base type* to be `readonly` (which means `object` would need to be changed to `readonly`) and it would need to be `sealed`.

Comment: since `object` has no fields or properties, I see no problem other than backwards compatibility to change it to `readonly`. However, if a `readonly` class requires it's base type to also be `readonly`, than it can't also be required to be `sealed`, unless using some compiler trickery that force all readonly class to implicitly inherit an abstract readonly base class (like all structs inherits system.ValueType) - which kinda makes them more value-types than reference types IMHO.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that line of reasoning. A `readonly struct` means "all fields must be `readonly`, and all methods are implicitly `readonly`". I don't see why the same can't apply to classes, where it enforces that all fields must be `readonly` and implicitly makes all methods `readonly`. Why would it also have to make the class `sealed`? You could enforce that all child classes have to also be `readonly`, but I'm not sure what you lose by not doing this

Comment: @ZoharPeled "However, if a readonly class requires it's base type to also be readonly, than it can't also be required to be sealed," - ah, I see what you mean; I guess that's part of the complications that explain why it wasn't trivially added - what exactly *are* the rules? what methods count as "readonly? is it a guarantee of "true" immutability? or just that "nothing at this level or below will change"... but what about virtual methods, interfaces (recalling that you can re-declare interfaces in subclasses, even if you've implemented them already), etc; very complex

Comment: @canton7 probably the same answer as I gave to Zohar